# Multiple PowerApps Linked to Single SharePoint List?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

Our organization created a SharePoint list that stores case review data. There are two separate teams that need the ability to manually enter data into the list fields. I have been using a PowerApps customized list form for data entry. However, I have not found a way to change the visible fields in the form based on which group is viewing the list or which SharePoint list view they select. I would like for each group to see different fields that are relevant to their particular portion of the case review. 
Would a standalone app work better for this situation? Is it possible to have two different standalone app views that link back and allow manual entry to the same SharePoint list?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is write a FLOW which returns current user's group and trigger this flow on visible property of the screen and set a global variable say "grpName" to the value returned from the FLOW. you can use this value in your app and show/hide fields.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, your needs first we start with the issue of permissions.

But SharePoint does not currently provide permissions at the list field level.

In addition , a form within a PowerApps app could only be linked to only one SP list. If you want to create multiple different forms using PowerApps for linking to same one SharePoint list, I afraid that there is no way to achieve your needs in PowerApps currently.

If you would like this feature to be added in PowerApps, please submit an idea to PowerApps Ideas Forum:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/PowerApps-Ideas/idb-p/PowerAppsIdeas